# Javascript click button stop after inputting the value. Also stop incrementing value after value=inputed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to stop mytimer() if the counter value is equal to number i.e. input value. Click button should not work on empty input and also after task is completed.Right now when you click on submit button it increase counter by 1. The reset button should reset the counter and clear the input.The restart button should restart the counter. In this I am highlighting boxes on every 3 & 5 Second.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#num").click(function(){
  var number = parseInt($('#display').text(), 10) || 0;
  var counter = setInterval(function () { mytimer()}, 1000);
  function mytimer() {
    number++;

    var max = $('#int').val() || number;
    $('.box1').css('background-color', number % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
    $('.box2').css('background-color', number % 5 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
    $('#display').text(number);

    if (number >= max) {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }

  // $('#display').text(number);
});

});
var MAX = 'number';
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sangeet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sangeet.css">
</head>
<body>

<form>
  Enter the Number <br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Number" value="input" id="int">
  <button type="button" value="Submit" id="num">Click Me</button>
  <p id="display"></p>
</form>

<div>
<div class="box1">
  <p>YES</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <p>NO</p>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="reset"> Reset </button>
<button type="button" id="restart"> Restart </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K so I tried to document it and wire up your other buttons too.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var interval;
  var $maximumValue = $('#int');
  var $currentValue = $('#display');
  var finished = false;
  
  function mytimer () {
   //parse a string "0" if the current value is blank
   var currentValue = parseInt($currentValue.text().trim() || "0", 10);
    var maximumValue = parseInt($maximumValue.val(), 10);
    
    //perform the logic if the maximum hasn't been reached
    if (currentValue < maximumValue) {
     currentValue++;
      
      $('.box1').css('background-color', currentValue % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
      $('.box2').css('background-color', currentValue % 5 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
      $currentValue.text(currentValue);
    } else {
        //stop the timer, marking it as having reached the maximum
        stoptimer(true);
    }
  }
  
  function starttimer () {
   //don't start another interval if one already is started, or if the maximum is not given
   if (!interval && $maximumValue.val().trim().length) {
     //clear previous fields
     $currentValue.text('');
     $('.box1, .box2').css('background-color', '');
      //start the new timer
      interval = setInterval(mytimer, 1000);
    }
  }
  
  function stoptimer (timerFinished) {
   //set if the timer stopped because it reached the end
    finished = (timerFinished === true);
  if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    //remove the interval so we can start a new one later
    interval = null;
    
    //clear previous fields if terminated prematurely
    if (!finished) {
     $currentValue.text('');
     $('.box1, .box2').css('background-color', '');
    }
  }
  
 $('#num').on('click', function(){
   //only start the timer if the last timer didn't finish
   if (!finished) starttimer();
  });
  
  $('#reset').on('click', function(){
   //stop any on going timer
   stoptimer();
    //clear the maximum value for new value
    $maximumValue.val('');
  });
  
  $('#restart').on('click', function(){
   //stop any on going timer
   stoptimer();
    //start the timer again
    starttimer();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Enter the Number <br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Number" value="input" id="int">
  <button type="button" value="Submit" id="num">Click Me</button>
  <p id="display"></p>
</form>

<div>
<div class="box1">
  <p>YES</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <p>NO</p>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="reset"> Reset </button>
<button type="button" id="restart"> Restart </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 var number = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var counter;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#num").click(function () {
            number = parseInt($('#display').text(), 10) || 0;
            max = parseInt($('#int').val(), 10) || number;
            if (number != max) {
                counter = setInterval(function () { mytimer() }, 1000);
            }
        });
        $("#reset").click(function () {
            clearInterval(counter);
            $('#display').text('');
            $('#int').val('');
        });
        $("#restart").click(function () {
            number = 0;
            max = parseInt($('#int').val(), 10) || number;
            if (number != max) {
                counter = setInterval(function () { mytimer() }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });

    function mytimer() {
        number++;
        $('.box1').css('background-color', number % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
        $('.box2').css('background-color', number % 5 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
        $('#display').text(number);

        if (number >= max) {
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sangeet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sangeet.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        Enter the Number <br>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Number" value="input" id="int">
        <button type="button" value="Submit" id="num">Click Me</button>
        <p id="display"></p>
    </form>

    <div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>YES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box2">
            <p>NO</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="reset"> Reset </button>
    <button type="button" id="restart"> Restart </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir! That works. Can you Please tell my how to restart the process by clicking Restart button.

Comment: hope this helps.